# How to update a datatable upon successful submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF and I have a small form to submit data and display it in a datatable. My problem is how to update (refresh table with new added data) the datatable after a successfull submit without refreshing the page. I am using tomcat and primefaces 3.5. Here is my JSF code.

```
    <p:tabView dynamic="true" id="tabview" cache="true" style="min-height: 500px;">
        <p:tab title="first Tab">
            <h:form id="form_reg>
                <p:panel header="Settings" style="width:50%;" >
                    <p:messages showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panel_group" >
                        <h:outputLabel value="Name"/>
                        <p:inputText size="60" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Revenue Group" value="#{mybean.name}"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton  value="Register User" icon="ui-icon-circle-plus" action="#{mybean.registeruser}"/>
</p:panel>
            </h:form>
            <h:form >
            <p:dataTable paginator="true" value="#{mybean.allusers}" var="user" id="user_table">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.id}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView >
```

Comment: You missed closing for `<p:panel>` and `<p:commandButton>`.

Comment: @EganWolf even after closing I am unable to update the datable that my biggest challenge. Look at the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `user_table` resides in a different and unnamed form as the button, you are unable to update it now.

Name the second form (`<h:form id="myForm"`) and update the `p:dataTable` from your `p:commandButton` using

`update=":tabview:myForm:user_table"`

Comment: am getting this error when I try your answer. Cannot find component with identifier ":myForm:user_table" referenced from "tabview:form_reg

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect the changes I mentioned.

Comment: I have edited my post severally and I cant do it again I don't have enough reputation. What is the solution to my  post

Comment: Please try to change the buttons update to the following: `update=":tabview:myForm:user_table"`

Comment: OK, I edited my post to reflect this correction. The next steps could be for you to check whether the method behind the `value` of the table is being called after the update and if yes, if it has changed as you wish - and if not, why the value has not changed through your code.

Comment: How can I verify whether the method has been called

Comment: Logger? Debugger? Sorry, but this is basic programming - I assume the original problem is solved with the absence of any JSF error.

Comment: What about how to perform filter on a datable? using primefaces